# Polymer app-layout sliding behind components

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I try to use the polymer app-layout but the menu slides behind my buttons and leaflet map. If i scroll down, it the content is still on top of the header. I tried to fix it with z-index but without any success. I use typscript and Polymer 3 in this project.

**nav-bar.ts**

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from "@polymer/polymer";
import "@polymer/iron-icons/iron-icons.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-header/app-header.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.js";
import "@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button.js";
import '@polymer/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.js';
import '@polymer/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.js';
import './my-app.js'

class NavBar extends PolymerElement {
static get template() {
return html`
<style>
    app-header {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #C62828;
      --app-header-background-front-layer: {
        background-position: 50% 10%;
      };
    }
    [main-title] {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    </style>
    <app-drawer-layout>
      <app-drawer swipe-open slot="drawer">
        <section>
          <h2>app-header </h2>     
          <h2>app-header </h2>
        </section>
      </app-drawer>
      <app-header-layout>
        <app-header fixed="true"  shadow="true" condenses="true"
      slot="header">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button  drawer-toggle>,
            <iron-icon icon="search"></iron-icon></paper-icon-button>
            <div condensed-title>Test</div>
          </app-toolbar>
          <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
          <app-toolbar>
            <div main-title spacer>Test</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
    <my-app appTitle="my app"></my-app>
    `;
}}
customElements.define("nav-bar", NavBar);
```

Even if I copy past one of their demos from: [webcomponents.org app-layout](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/app-layout) its the same problem. I also tried using this in my index.html but with the same result:

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar> 
<my-app></my-app>
```

This is how it looks:
[scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxsP8.png) the button "Test" is from my-app and not in the header
[with the menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYeTM.png) another [example with leaflet map and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htStc.png)
Is there any way I can change this behaviour and always have the header and the menu as the first layer?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you separate toolbar with drawer, it will work as you wish.

Here a working example: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-app-layout-sliding-behind-components)

```
import { PolymerElement } from "@polymer/polymer";
import {html} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/html-tag.js';

import "@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js";
import '@polymer/iron-icons/iron-icons.js';

import "@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-header/app-header.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.js";
import "@polymer/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.js";
import "@vaadin/vaadin-button/vaadin-button.js";
import '@polymer/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.js';
import '@polymer/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.js';
import './my-app.js';
class NavBar extends PolymerElement {
static get properties() { return {
  drawerOpened:{type:Boolean}
}}
static get template() {
return html`
<style>
    host:{
      display:block;
      background-color:red;
    }
    app-header {
      color: '#fff';
      background-color: grey;

    }
    [main-title] {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    app-toolbar.tb1 { background-color: yellow;}
    app-toolbar.tb2 { background-color: green;}
    app-toolbar.tb3 { background-color: brown;}
    paper-icon-button { color: white }
    app-drawer > * { padding: 20px;}
    </style>

        <app-header fixed="true"  shadow="true" condenses="true"
      slot="header">
          <app-toolbar spacer class='tb1'>
            <paper-icon-button  icon='menu' on-tap='drawerToggle'></paper-icon-button>
            <div condensed-title> Tool Bar-1</div>
          </app-toolbar>
          <app-toolbar class='tb2'></app-toolbar>
          <app-toolbar class='tb3'>
            <div main-title spacer>Main Title</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
      <app-drawer-layout>
      <app-drawer opened="{{drawerOpened}}" swipe-open slot="drawer">

          <h1> Side Menu</h1>
          <h2> App-header </h2>     
          <h2> App-header </h2>

      </app-drawer>
      </app-drawer-layout>
    <my-app appTitle="my app"></my-app>
    `;}


    drawerToggle(){
       this.drawerOpened = !this.drawerOpened;
    }

}
customElements.define("nav-bar", NavBar);
```